# PrimeNG DataTable - dataTable model updates but looses current selection

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have a DataTable that is bound to a model that is refreshed ever 10 seconds via polling my api. The data refreshes fine but I have a bug tied to the selection.

If I have selected one or more rows it will stay selected when the data is refreshed. However, if I also open a primeng dialog box the dataTable changes and the row is no longer selected.

When I inspect the data for my `[selection]` and even in the dataTable's selection property (via `@ViewChild()`) the row is still selected but it does not reflect in the UI. This causes some serious data tracking issues.

Comment: you should be having the clone of the selected table Data. explain your component structure or create a working plunker

Comment: Have a similar issue. Did you find the resolution ?